# Shabbos and National Security

Tags: halacha, shabbat

A doctor is allowed to drive to the hospital on Shabbos for an emergency *to save the patient's life*. No one really argues on that principle.

Now suppose someone works in a high level position in the CIA or the Pentagon. Is there a heter for that person to drive to his office on Shabbos if he's being called for a potential National Security threat?

Comment: If someone's life is at stake, why would he not?

Comment: Because perhaps we can make a distinction. The doctor is actively trying to save patient X. The CIA analyst may be called to asses a piece of intelligence pertaining to whether or not a mission should get a green light or not. Is that a case of saving a life where one can violate Shabbos

Comment: "a potential National Security threat" is safek pikuach nefesh. If the case is not pikuach nefesh, then why would he be able to go in?

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought safek pikuach nefesh also allows, if not requires you to violate Shabbos

Comment: @SAH Indeed it does! Save first, ask later.

Comment: I know of someone whose rav told him to go in to the office (of a three letter agency) and stay there over Shabbos after September 11, 2001 (or similar cases).